# Differences between HMAC and HKDF in a specific case

Tags: hash, hmac, key-derivation, mac, hkdf

I want to use a key derivation function to derive a key from another one.

I think HKDF is the easiest solution in my case.

[This explanation](http://webee.technion.ac.il/%7Ehugo/kdf/hkdf-fig.jpg) gives a clear definition of HKDF.

In the case where the number of key bits requested from the KDF is equal to the hash output length (i.e. `L = k` in the definition), do I have to compute 2 HMACs:

`PRK = HMAC(XTS, SKM)` and `K(1) = HMAC(PRK, CTXinfo)`

or can I directly compute:

`K(1) = HMAC(SKM, CTXinfo)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HKDF stage 1 is useful for when the SKM value is derived using some deterministic method, such as a key exchange, or from a source that may not be fully trusted. SKM may be substantially larger than the keys you want, but may have the entropy not evenly distributed. Stage 1 compacts and distributes the entropy into a key that is correctly sized for the hash function in stage 2.

If you have a source key from a true random number generator, or that has already gone through a strong KDF, you can substitute PRK with SKM, and skip the first HMAC operation.